# jaxb binding random string to xs:boolean 'true'

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have an xml element defined as boolean, but when I pass in a string 'blablabla', it gets marshalled to true.

Here's the xsd:

```
    <xs:complexType name="usageAttributesType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="force-reservation" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="force-purchase" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
        .............
```

And the request xml looks like this:

```
<usage-auth-rate-charge>
  <msisdn>444fh7775hweff</msisdn>
  <service-id>c001</service-id>
  <usage-attributes>
    <force-purchase>toast</force-purchase>
```

In my java I have :

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.mycompany.binding.request" );
jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xml);
```

And the bound jaxb object has the forcePurchase flag set to true.  If I leave it out of the xml request, or set it to false, the flag will be set to false (correctly).

Can anyone tell me why it's parsing 'toast' as true?  Incidentally it doesn't matter what string I put in there, it always gets parsed as true...

For annoying historical reasons, we are using jaxb 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) the behaviour is the opposite, invalid boolean values (values other than `true` and `1`) will be set to `false`.

**Java Model (Foo)**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private boolean bar;

    public boolean isBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(boolean bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader xml = new StringReader("<foo><bar>toast</bar></foo>");
        Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        System.out.println(foo.isBar());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
false
```

---

**Detecting the Invalid Value**

If you specify a `ValidationEventHandler` on the `Unmarshaller` you can detect the conversion issue.  The default `ValidationEventHandler` carries on when an invalid boolean value is encountered and in JAXB 2 sets the value to false.

```
    unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent ve) {
            System.out.println(ve.getMessage());
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Now the output is the following:

```
String "toast" is not valid boolean value.
false
```

Comment: Thanks Blaise for your quick response.  The one thing missing from your answer was that I had to switch on validation for the unmarshaller like this: `unmarshaller.setValidating(true);`

Comment: In fact I've discovered that in jaxb 1.0 the default validation handler handles this case correctly, so I don't need to over-ride it, but I do need to switch on validation.